# Azure-cli set keyvalue secret value through powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-keyvault, azure-cli

I want to set the secret value with a URL that contains "&", for example: http://ttt.com?p=p&data=1.
But "&" is the key word of powershell, so after calling

```
$v="http://ttt.com?p=p&data=1"
az keyvault secret set --vault-name "XXX" --name "XXX" --value "$v"
```

The actual value will be `http://ttt.com?p=p`.

I tried it with single quotation $v='http://ttt.com?p=p&data=1' or $v="http://ttt.com?p=p`&data=1", both of them don't work.

Comment: I can't seem to repro this in the Azure Portal Cloud Shell, in either Bash or PowerShell. If the URL is surrounded in double quotes, then it handles the ampersand correctly.

Comment: @Adriano Thanks. What's the result if you try it locally? (Windows powershell)

Comment: It also works for me in Windows PowerShell.

Comment: I can reproduce your issue locally, it works fine in azure cloud shell, may be a bug?

Comment: @Adriano Could you provide the screenshot of detail command?

Comment: @JoyWang The reason is that "&" is the key word of powershell. So we need to escape it.

Answer (score 4):

Try surrounding the ampersand with double quotes. For example:

```
PS C:\Users\Adriano> $v = 'http://ttt.com?p=p"&"data=1'
PS C:\Users\Adriano> az keyvault secret set --vault-name "adriano-testvault" --name "my-secret" --value $v
{
  "attributes": {
    "created": "2018-09-20T08:35:25+00:00",
    "enabled": true,
    "expires": null,
    "notBefore": null,
    "recoveryLevel": "Purgeable",
    "updated": "2018-09-20T08:35:25+00:00"
  },
  "contentType": null,
  "id": "https://adriano-testvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/my-secret/be022c3cfe034bfb83321a35a5919ccf",
  "kid": null,
  "managed": null,
  "tags": {
    "file-encoding": "utf-8"
  },
  "value": "http://ttt.com?p=p&data=1"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to do it without modifying the URL?